# Is an empty 'else' statement required for 'safe' programming?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

I have recently been reading some code automatically generated by MATLAB/Real Time Workshop from a model, and read whiat seems to be a very strange justification for using some code:

```
if (u <= x[bottom]) {
    retValue = bottom;
    returnStatus = 1U;
} else if (u >= x[top]) {
    retValue = top-1;
    returnStatus = 1U;
} else {
    /* else required to ensure safe programming, even *
    * if it's expected that it will never be reached */
}
```

It seems like the coder is justifying having an empty 'else' statement at the end by calling it 'safe programming'. Unless there is some obscure memory management reason for it, it seems like a very unnecessary thing to include.

For what reason could it be there?

**Edit:**

I found the full source, it is in fact not auto-generated but copied from rt_look.c:

http://ecmc.rochester.edu/ecmc/docs/supercollider/scbook/Ch23_Dialects/extensions_c23_dialects/ENIAC/Eniac_Cycling%20Source%20Code/rt_look.c

Comment: It's auto-generated code.  Perhaps they're just doing that because it composes better.

Comment: there are cases that `u \in (x[bottom], x[top])`?

Comment: I would call that _confusing programming_. Why is there an empty else? Did you forget to add the code? Should I be worried an error checking is missing?

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything but it's not a practice I've seen before.

Comment: He's trying to use it as an empty "default" but it's no different than not having anything there at all. If nothing else is true, the empty else will activate, doing nothing. If it weren't there and none of the conditions were met, then the entire if-else structure would be skipped with the same result: no actions taken.

Comment: Useful for debugging!

Comment: Actually, the opposite idiom is often useful: `if (false) {}
else if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ... } ...` because all conditions (including the first) are aligned.

Comment: Since this is Simulink generated code, it might have to do with an automotive coding standard like MISRA, which tend to impose some strange notions of *safety*. For instance, MISRA-C requires a `default` clause in all `switch-case` statements, even if they're empty. In this case the intent might be to tell the reader that the `else` code path was not inadvertently left out, but it is meant to be a NOP. If that is indeed the case, then it's just a poor comment.

Comment: For a chained `if` like that it *is* wise to provide the final else, and include in it either a comment that that path is a no-op, or `assert(FALSE)`, if the path should never be taken.  The block should not be totally empty, since a year later no one will remember whether it's a "don't care" or "will never happen".

Answer (score 5):

Considering the case you presented, when the block of code can never be reached. I agree with Shabaz in that it makes for *confusing* code. If I had read the code without the question or topic I would be wondering what I was missing. It *is* quite useful for debugging if you expect that portion of code to change... but I think a good old `assert()` does just as good. To answer your question, I don't believe an **empty** else statement serves any purpose.

Answer (score 3):

some coding guidlines (MISRA for example) require an else-branch after else-if cosntructs or they will output warnings because somebody may have forgotten the the case.

Comment: How popular is the opinion/guideline that else should always follow else-if? Is it just MISRA? Based on your experience is more commonly suggested that an empty else should or shouldn't be included? I've only been coding a few years, so I'm wondering if I just haven't been exposed to enough guidelines. But personally, I have not seen many empty else statements in my carrier.

Answer (score 2):

Some coding standards require authors to add default and final else clauses to ensure that it is documented that the person writing the code thought about what would happen if the code falls through all of the other possibilities.  It clearly will not affect the program one way or the other to have the empty else or default so I'm not sure if I agree in calling that safe programming.  It doesn't hurt to document that the author intended for that fall through to occur, but that is more of a maintenance and documentation enhancement.  Perhaps the idea is that if the author has to put in a comment that they will think more about the structure of the program in order to reduce the risk of bad consequences if none of the conditions are met.

I just realized that I didn't provide a yes or no.  My answer is no, because it is not required to make a program safe.  One could easily make an argument that it improves documentation and results in more critical thinking about all possibilities, but even if it is used I don't see how one could ever answer yes to such a question.

Comment: I've been in many code reviews where the code would be (justifiably) "failed" if there wasn't a comment along that path explaining when it occurred and what was expected/intended.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of general `if-else` blocks, it is not necessary to have an empty `else` block. Not including an empty `else` block does not make the code any more unsafe and including an empty `else` block does not make the code any more safe.

Looking at the code you have presented, the `else` block should be encountered when `u` lies between `x[bottom]` and `x[top]`. Are you supposed to ignore those values? The comments indicate as if the user of the function has to make sure that `u` lies between `x[bottom]` and `x[top]`. If you are counting on the user to abide by that constraint, I agree with Sean Pedersen that an `assert()` in the `else` block is a good thing to do to enforce the assumption in the code.

Comment: I added the full source around the above snippet online, link attached. The method is a lookup method and does exactly what you would expect. It hits the empty 'else' clause, does nothing, then continues on to handle those cases. Seems even more absurd.

Comment: From the linked source code, it seems that the code under the statement ` if (returnStatus == 0U)` belongs under the `else` block. That means adding an `assert()` in the `else` clause will not be appropriate.